# ble on windows api c++

Tags: c++, windows, bluetooth

I am getting 0000000 when I try to search ble device depending on the guuid. What can be resulting this?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR *argv[]) {
    GUID AGuid;
    CLSIDFromString((LPWSTR) TEXT(MOSS_DEVICE_UUID), &AGuid);

    HANDLE hLEDevice = GetBLEHandle(AGuid);

    std::cout << hLEDevice; --> returns 0000000

    return 0;
}
```

full code :https://codeshare.io/2BJOzL

Comment: What is BluetoothInterfaceGUID? Use DIGCF_PROFILE instead of DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE. Use SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo instead fo SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces. Probably other errors.

Comment: that is. AGuid.

Comment: I know that that is GUID but value?

Comment: returns this when parsed 00745230  OLECHAR* guidString;
    StringFromCLSID(AGuid, &guidString);

Comment: is that guuid is enumator of the bluetooth dongle in pc devices/bluetooth? {e0cbf06c-cd8b-4647-bb8a-263b43f0f974}

Comment: OK, CLSID is correct, make other changes I described and make sure your device is paired.

Comment: there is another way to connect with sockets what s the difference? currently access violation actually

Comment: i need to send pair request also is that possible?

Comment: Yes, use WinRT Bluetooth API sintead of legacy one. Or pair with Windows Add Bluetooth Device dialog.

Comment: I try to connect with this very simple socket but error is -1 https://codeshare.io/5XjBnn

Comment: Bluetooth sockets on Windows does not support BLE. BLE has absolutely different communication mechanism.

Comment: is there a working example?

Comment: example for legacy which supports ble

Comment: your code is exactly legacy API example (with just a few wrong function calls).

Comment: WinRT BLE samples can be found by this link: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE

Comment: Or use third party libraries: 32feet, Bluetooth Framework